# Read multiple image php

Tags: php, image, header

I have two separate files, one is to display the html/php document image, and the other is a php file that renders the image using the header function content-type:image/jpeg.

I tried using it with one image and it works well. However, I need to display multiple images. How could I do this?

The html/php doc has an img tag that points out to the php file that renders the image

```
echo "<image src=Image.php>";
```

The image.php

```
$selectimage = mysql_query("SELECT Image from ImageTbl", $con);
if($selectimage)
{
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($selectimage))
{
echo $row["Image"];
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by displaying multiple images -- do you want to use that script to display a number of images as one image, i.e. one next to another?

Answer (score 0):

make two files one for image another for fetching the row like this

image.php

```
$image_id = $_GET["id"];
header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
//query database to get only one image from id
echo $row["Image"];
```

another file

getimages.php

```
//query for image data
while($row = mysql_fetch_array())
{
     echo "<img src='image.php?id=$row[id]' />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't output all the images together, because to the browser, it will look like the data of multiple images mushed together, which is nonsensical. Also, each image tag can only display one image. To solve this, give the image table an ID field to identify the image.

Then in the file that outputs HTML, do something like this (passing the ID for the image you need):

```
echo "<image src='Image.php?id=1>";
echo "<image src='Image.php?id=2>";
echo "<image src='Image.php?id=3>";
```

And then in the file that outputs the image, do:

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']); // intval will validate the ID to be an int
$selectimage = mysql_query("SELECT Image from ImageTbl WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1", $con);
if ($selectimage) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($selectimage);
    if ($row) { // check if the image really exists
        header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
        echo $row["Image"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't teach people to use $_REQUEST as everyone knows it holds a bad reputation with security and speed. - Use $_POST or $_GET instead depending on which method you want to use.

Comment: Hate to be contrary, but while I agree that using the correct method variable is commendable, I think the security/speed bad rep is snake oil. One shouldn't rely on the method to protect a script -- it's no replacement for proper input validation. Also, nothing in this script naturally indicates that one method should be preferred (except that I happen to use GET). Since $_REQUEST is not populated on demand, it has the same speed as the rest, so not sure where the speed argument comes from. There are, however, good arguments against $_REQUEST, such as here: http://bit.ly/3OZUbp :)

Comment: Oh, I do apologize maybe I was wrong about the speed, however I also agree that the security should NEVER be entirely based on your method. Obviously sanitizing all data is key to any application. I wasn't having a go at you, I was just trying to let the OP acknowledge that they need to be careful with the REQUEST var.

Comment: Quite agree. I think we're on the same page. It's better safe than sorry where security comes in, after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop to loop through the requested records and echo them out independently to the img tags which your using.

That would be the best way in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display number of different images using one script, try to add some unique hash to the script name ( for e.g. `md5( microtime() )` )

```
$seed = md5( microtime() );
echo '<image src="Image.php' . $seed . '">';
```